# Google Maps slow in Samsung devices

Tags: android, google-maps, samsung-mobile

I am working on an Android app that uses Google Maps. Relevant libraries are:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
```

I cannot share the map activity code because it belongs to my company. But, it works fine on our Nexus and Huawei test devices. On the Samsung test devices (one running 4.1, one running 5.0), it runs, but is *really* slow.

I have tried targeting the versions for the specific versions of the devices, but this did not help. On the Samsung devices only, the delay is noticeable when:

- loading the map for the first time (takes 4-5 seconds)
- zooming in or out after it has loaded (2-3 second delay)
- panning around is choppy too, with the tiles rendering haphazardly

So, my question is: what the heck is going on here? And, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I have used and tested maps on Galaxy S6 couple of days ago, and they work fine. I didn't need other gradle play services except for this one:

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'

I am curious how you load the map or what you do with it.

Comment: I have found similar issues on Samsung devices when I display data on the map taken from the `assets` folder of the project (and thus, compiled into the apk). If this may help you please let me know and I will share my workaround.